# Erase blank cells in an excel table

Tags: excel, vba

I have this excel table, and I I want to locate in the first blank cell of column “C”, in the example: "C10", so I can erase the other rows, that don’t have any information related to "Px Actual".

My first choice was:

```
Range("C1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
```

Nevertheless, this code locates the first blank cell in “C17”, so I had to come with a second choice:

```
n = 2
Cells(n, 3).Select
Do While ActiveCell <> ""
Cells(n, 3).Select
If Trim(ActiveCell) = "" Then
Exit Do
Else
n = n + 1
End If
Loop
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
```

This was a way to solve the problem, but takes a lot of time, since I have to repeat the same process like in 20 other formulas, with tons of rows. Can anyone help me please?

Thank you in advance.
Data:
[image: Data]

Comment: Your 1st code doesn't work because the cells in the range `C10:C16` are **blank** (but not empty), while cell `C17` is **empty**. By using `Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select` twice in your 2nd code, with the first selection, you are selecting the blank cells and the first empty cell and with the second selection, you are probably adding the cells from the next cell to the bottom cell of the worksheet to the selection. That's a lot of rows to delete. Also, you don't need to use `Select` when locating the first blank cell which is possibly the main reason for the code being slow.

Comment: Are these blank cells always at the bottom of your data? Does your data (table) always start in cell `A1`? What does *"I have to repeat the same process like in 20 other formulas"* mean? Maybe you meant in 20 other worksheets?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer.

And yes the blank cell is always at the bottom of the data, since I reorder the data selecting the C column.
Yes the data always starts at A1
I have to repeat the same process, because basically every sheet is a different algorithm, and every algorithm goes with its own macro.
I will try your solution and let you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### Clear Bottom Blanks

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ClearBottomBlanksTEST()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    ClearBottomBlanks ws, 3
End Sub

Sub ClearBottomBlanks( _
        ByVal ws As Worksheet, _
        Optional ByVal BlankColumn As Long = 1)
    
    ' The data has to be contiguous (no empty rows or columns)
    ' and it has to start in cell 'A1'.
    
    ' Reference the range ('rg') and validate the column ('BlankColumn').
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    If rg.Columns.Count < BlankColumn Then Exit Sub ' not enough columns
    
    ' Attempt to reference the last non-blank ('xlValues') cell ('lCell')
    ' in the column.
    Dim lCell As Range
    Set lCell = rg.Columns(BlankColumn).Find("*", , xlValues, , , xlPrevious)
    If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data in column
    
    ' Calculate the number of rows ('rCount') to be cleared and validate it.
    Dim lRow As Long: lRow = lCell.Row
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count - lRow
    If rCount = 0 Then Exit Sub ' no blanks found
    
    ' Clear the rows.
    rg.Resize(rCount).Offset(lRow).Clear
    
End Sub
```